# How can I implement navigation routes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I have design my scenario to understanding about the flow.

**Dashboard Screen=> open side Drawer =>Select any menu=> First screen=> second screen=>open dialog(second screen)=> First screen=> Side drawer.**

I want to use above like this navigation flow, when I click inside the dialog button I want to go First screen than first screen to click back button so go to side drawer.

I'm using the below code for navigate screen.

Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(screenName);

Please suggest me to how I can implement my above mention flow.

Answer (score 0):

you can give each screen a route name like this :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routes: {
        "/home_page" : (context) => MyHomePage(),
        "/keep_alive": (context) => const KeepAliveExample()
      },
      initialRoute: "/home_page", 
    );
  }
}
```

- like this you will set all of your routes , and set an initial route that the application will run at the start.
- when you want to navigate to another screen you will do this :

  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(screenName);

and the screen name will be the route that you give it in the material app.

- you can change the pushNamed to others styles navigations like :

  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(newRouteName, (route) => false);
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(routeName);
  Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(routeName);